# multipart/form-data + Sockets = Server not Responding

Tags: c#, http, sockets, post

I'm using my own HTTP wrapper using sockets. So far everything works except multipart/form-data POST. When I send the data to server, it simply doesn't respond, so I'm guessing I'm missing something in my POST like I would need "\r\n\r\n" for regular requests.

This is my request:

```
POST /getproxies/get.php HTTP/1.1
Host: myhost.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Cookie: sid=UtozR43zQQAtVA2Np0KP_ZLnO0IYwwU1S_Tt4Z3N80wctL; 
Connection: Close
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------4664151417711
Content-Length: 411

---------------------------4664151417711
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="proxy_count"

20 proxies
---------------------------4664151417711
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="u"

13
---------------------------4664151417711
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="opt_1"


---------------------------4664151417711
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="opt_2"

GET
---------------------------4664151417711--
```

When I send the data, the connection is open, like it would be waiting on the server, but server doesn't respond. Any ideas what am I missing here? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your boundary isn't matching the one declared on the boundary= part.

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x

--AaB03x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit-name"

Larry
--AaB03x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="file1.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

... contents of file1.txt ...
--AaB03x--
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated the boundary to match with body, but still the same thing happens, all my boundaries match, except the last one that has additional -- at the end.. any ideas?

Comment: You have to add an additional -- at the beginning of the boundary everywhere it is used (except at the declaration). See the example, from the w3.org site.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked, would have never figured that one out.. :)

Answer (score 2):

> [RFC 2046 - Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions (MIME) Part Two: Media Types](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-5.1.1):

> The Content-Type field for multipart entities requires one parameter,
> "boundary". The boundary delimiter line is then defined as a line
> consisting entirely of two hyphen characters ("-", decimal value 45)
> followed by the boundary parameter value from the Content-Type header
> field, optional linear whitespace, and a terminating CRLF.

So I guess this should work:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=54472172614771
Content-Length: 47

--54472172614771
Your data
--54472172614771--
```

Please note the boundary specified in the boundary parameter of the Content-Type header should match the boundary you use in the payload. Also note the boundaries also count towards the Content-Length.

Comment: Ah, what a ridiculous protocol HTTP really can be.

Comment: I find the boundary stuff pretty absurd. Why not just send the length first so the receiver can assume the next X bytes are data?

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin It's more a MIME heritage than an HTTP thing really. And yes, it could've been achieved in an more aesthetically pleasing way I guess. The thing you describe already exists in the form of [chunked transfer encoding](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-3.6).

Comment: I matched the boundary with the body, but still receiving the same problem. Do I need to specify in boundary= the last boundary with additional --?

Comment: @user1192403 please update the question with your current progress.

Comment: Technically could I use just a regular post were multi-part post is expected? since it doesn't contain binary data would it work?